# Return internal IP from NetworkInterface Android

Tags: java, android, ipv4, inetaddress, network-interface

I am using the code to grab the IPv4 address my device is using:

```
public static String getIPAddress(boolean useIPv4) {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
            List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
            for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    String sAddr = addr.getHostAddress().toUpperCase();
                    boolean isIPv4 = InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(sAddr); 
                    if (useIPv4) {
                        if (isIPv4) 
                            return sAddr;
                    } else {
                        if (!isIPv4) {
                            int delim = sAddr.indexOf('%'); // drop ip6 port suffix
                            return delim<0 ? sAddr : sAddr.substring(0, delim);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { } // for now eat exceptions
    return "";
}
```

My Samsung Galaxy Express is connected to WiFi and has a sim card with cell enabled.

The IP I get back from the code above is the 10. address which indicates the phone is using the cell signal, when I need it to use the 192. address available from the network.

Is there a way to alter the code above to choose the 192. if available? Or is this the phone that's at fault?

I have tried disabling mobile network, placing into airplane mode etc.

The only thing that worked was removing the sim card!! I can't expect users to do this just to get an Internal address?

Thanks

Comment: Um, did you try examining *all* the interfaces? Your code ignores anything but the first, unless that's the loopback interface.

Comment: I have now got code that can put all IPs in a list, which includes the 192. address. However I want to automatically pick this IP out if available. 

There are many ways to find the index of an item in an Array but I want to find that item based on a half match. For example I want searching for "192" in the array to not come back as -1, but come back as the position the full 192 address appears in, does that make sense?

Comment: "does that make sense?" -- no, sorry, it does not. I am having some difficulty in interpreting your problem.

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer - If you have a hardcoded dependency on the value "192", that is the wrong way to do this. Some wifi routers use "10.x.y.z" address ranges and others use "172.x.y.z". I've given you some code below to identify the wlan0 adapter's ip address. You might want to modify it to filter out the interfaces you want to avoid instead of trying to guess the wifi adapter.  But let me ask this: **What are you really trying to do?** That is, why do you need to discover your own local IP address to begin with?  There may be a better way to get what you need.

Comment: Note that your app's own Internet operations will go over WiFi if there is an active WiFi connection, so it's not like you need the IP address for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be interested to know if there's a better way....

But for now, Look for the "wlan0" address. Also, the code below will filter out the loopback addresses for you.

```
List<NetworkInterface> interfaces;
try {
    interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
    for (NetworkInterface ni : interfaces)
    {
        if ((ni.isLoopback() == false) && ni.isUp() && (ni.getName().equals("wlan0")))
        {

            // enumerate ip addresses on this network interface (e.g. ni.getInetAddresses()

            // return the first one that is is Ipv4

        }
    }
```

You should combine the above code with calls to android.net.ConnectivityManager to confirm you are on wifi.

Comment: Note that this algorithm will have problems with devices using Ethernet (e.g., OUYA, Android TV) and perhaps other scenarios. Counting on `wlan0` being right name is risky. That being said, I don't know of anything better.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I agree 100%. Ideally, the best way to find the best interface (and IP) is to enumerate the routing table and find all the rows with 0.0.0.0 in the destination address column, and pick the one with the lowest metric (and use the IFace column of that selection). This could work by dropping down to the NDK and making all the usual Linux/Unix system calls.

Comment: But the OP said he wanted the Wifi address, not necessarily the best address. I've asked the OP in the comments of his question to identify what he's really trying to do.